# t-test with negative and positive variable values?

Tags: correlation, t-test, mean

Can I use a t-test for variables with negtive and positive values?

Comment: Imagine that you have Celsius temperatures for two Northern Hemisphere places and two months say $-20$ and $0$ in January and $0$ and $20$ in July.  Averaging $-20$ and $10$ to get $-5$ makes perfect sense, just as much sense as averaging $0$ and $20$ to get $10$. Negative values aren't any kind of barrier to taking averages. And if an average is $0$ that's fine too.

Answer (score 2):

So you have two variables, two vectors with (Pearson) correlation coefficients? And you want to compare the mean correlation coefficient for each variable?

This is a case for a t-test. However, because your variables are bounded in -1 and 1 this may cause problems with one of the assumptions of the test, the normally distributed errors. You should check those. Otherwise use a non-parametric test (such as Welch).

Also, a t-test works with negative values just fine.